# How to use android bootstrap?

Tags: android, gradle, android-bootstrap

I want to use android bootstrap in my new application, I have gone through couple of tutorials for this.And when I tried to build with maven, it says there is no POM ,make sure you are running maven from correct directory.
I am using maven version:3.3.3
And downloaded android bootstrap from here:https://github.com/AndroidBootstrap/android-bootstrap
Please help.